# How to get session in Next.js middleware? (error in deploy)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware, vercel

```
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, ev: NextFetchEvent) {
  const requestForNextAuth = {
    headers: {
      cookie: req.headers.get("cookie"),
    },
  };
  //@ts-ignore
  const session = await getSession({ req: requestForNextAuth });

  if (
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/fictions/create") &&
    (!req.cookies.get("~~session") || !session)
  ) {
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/enter", req.url));
  }

  if (
    req.nextUrl.pathname.includes("/edit") &&
    (!req.cookies.get("~~session") || !session)
  ) {
    return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/enter", req.url));
  }

  if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/profile") && !session) {
    if (!session) {
      return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/enter", req.url));
    }
  }
}
```

Error Message :
"Dynamic Code Evaluation (e. g. 'eval', 'new Function', 'WebAssembly.compile') not allowed in Edge Runtime
Learn More: [https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/edge-dynamic-code-evaluation"](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/edge-dynamic-code-evaluation%22)

It worked well with local but seems I did something wrong because it seems to cause errors in when deploying project.

I want unauthorized people redirected to '/enter' page by using next-auth session.
So I used getSession.
Is it wrong way to get session in 'edge'?
Then what I should do for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well you are trying to check in `_middleware.js` whether the current user is logged in or not ?
You cannot use `getSession()` here.

Here is my workaround, it's working in local (didn't try in production yet) :

```
 export async function middleware(req) {

    const pathname = req.nextUrl.pathname

    const session = await getToken({ req: req, secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET }); // I am getting the session here

    // Protect protected pages
    if (arrayOfProtectedPaths.includes(pathname)) {
        if (session === null) {
            return NextResponse.redirect("http://localhost:3008/spots/allSpots")
        }
    }

    // Prevent logged in user to access to register and sign in 
    if (shouldNotBeUser.includes(pathname)) {
        if (session !== null) {
            return NextResponse.redirect("http://localhost:3008/spots/allSpots")
        }
    }
}
```